# How to get address of the right specific static overloaded c++ operator function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, memory-address

Take the following code as an example.

```
struct A0{};
struct A1: A0{};
struct A2: A0{};

int operator<<(A1& a, int i){}
int operator<<(A2& a, int i){}

using FA0 = int(*)(A0&,int);
using FA1 = int(*)(A1&,int);

int main()
{
    FA0 fa0 = ::operator<<;
}
```

How can i have fa0 point to the first overloaded << operator? I guess, same question also applies to functions with normal name.

Comment: No, my question is a bit different (from that of std::for_each). In my case, the function point is to be assigned to a function pointer of specific type (FA0). I need a explicit cast here.

Comment: However, the answer in the other question does answer to my question. So, question can be dismissed.